# como puedo desactivar que el texto del edittex no sea borrado por el boton del teclado?, quiero desactivar el boton

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero que el texto del edittex no sea borrado por el boton de borrar del teclado del celular, es decir que quede desactivado, y que solo pueda limpiar el edittex por medio de un boton agregado por mi en la interfaz de android, esto es en android studio, como puedo lograr eso?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.